# How can I make a new color?

Tags: c#, winforms, colors

I have a form in C# that I want to enter as red, green and blue in 3 `TextBox` controls and make a new color. For example: red=3, green=2, blue=5
when I click on "MAKE COLOR" button, a label shows me the new color.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Let us assume that you have some code that looks similar to this:

```
int red = Convert.ToInt32(RedColorComponentValueTextBox.Text);
int green = Convert.ToInt32(GreenColorComponentValueTextBox.Text);
int blue = Convert.ToInt32(BlueColorComponentValueTextBox.Text);
//Don't forget to try/catch this
```

Then to create the color from these values, try

```
Color c = Color.FromArgb(red, green, blue);
```

Then set the `ForeColor` property (or the `BackColor` property -- not sure which one you meant to change) of the label to `c`.

You will need to have

```
using System.Drawing;
```

in your code file (or class) preamble.

Note: If you wanted to also have an alpha component, you could try this:

```
Color c = Color.FromArgb(alpha, red, green, blue);
```

General hint: If you want to use an HTML/CSS color specification of the form `#RRGGBB` e.g. `#335577`, try this pattern

```
int red = 0x33, green = 0x55, blue = 0x77;
```

Comment: what about when the color is #f0f0f0 ?

Answer (score 4):

Use [FromRgb](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.color.fromrgb.aspx) to create custom colors:

```
Color myRgbColor = new Color();
myRgbColor = Color.FromRgb(3, 2, 5);
```

Comment: @miltiadis: it says: can not 'red' it doesn't exit in current context

Comment: FromRgb method is from Color class from the namespace System.Windows.Media from the assembly PresentationCore.dll, which you can add to the references of your project. BUT this Color class collides with the Color class from System.Drawing and you can't convert between those when assigning to for example a Button.BackColor