# How to set variable color for a Windows Forms color property

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm a beginner, and I think that the solution is very simple, but I can't find it all over the Internet.

I'm looking for a way of setting the back color of forms and controls to a certain color variable so if I change its value to green for exapmple, every control that its back color set to mainColor will turn green and that the changes will show up in the designer.

```
public class MainForm:Form
{
    public static Color mainColor=[some color];
    public static Color secColor=[some color];
    public Main()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BackColor=mainColor;
        control1.BackColor=secColor;
        control2.BackColor=secColor;
        control3.BackColor=secColor;
    }
}
```

Like that by changing mainColor and secColor. The controls are changed, but it wont show up in the designer. What is the right way of doing it?

Comment: Pretty important to know how the designer works.  It creates an instance of your *base* class at design-time.  If you change a property of that base class in the Properties window then you can see that.  But your constructor does *not* run at design-time.  That couldn't work, you'd have to compile your project first and that's a chicken-and-egg problem.  A UserControl could do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is called DataBinding, and it's done partly with the Designer and partly with code.

Instead of declaring

```
public static Color mainColor=[some color];
```

declare it as a property:

```
    public Color MyColor
    {
        get
        {
            return myColor;
        }
        set
        {
            myColor = value;
        }
    }
```

In your main form, edit each of the controls that you want to be influenced by this variable to bind their color property to it. I'll use a Panel as the sample control, so add some Panel objects to your form. Then in each Panel object, in the Properties panel, click the + next to **DataBindings**, then click in the empty box next to **(Advanced)**. Click the ellipsis (...) and select the **BackColor** property. Then, under the **Binding** dropdown, select **Add Project Data Source**. Select **Object** in the next dialog and navigate to your form, and select that. A list of properties will then appear in the **Formatting and Advanced Binding** dialog box and you can select your property **MyColor**.

Note that once you have created this data source for the first one, you won't need to recreate it for each Panel - just reference the one you created already.

You can then change the BackColor of any of the controls you did this databinding on by changing the value of the MyColor property in your program. They will all change together.

You will probably also need to arrange that property to broadcast the message that it has changed, so add this line to the set() method.

```
form1BindingSource.ResetBindings(false);
```

so that the set method looks like this.

```
set
{
    myColor = value;
    form1BindingSource.ResetBindings(false);
}
```

That tells the binding source object to notify all subscribers to update themselves, and it will happen automatically every time the MyColor property is changed.

Comment: Now I have tried it out but it didnt worked. I did exactly as you wrote but the color hasn't changed. is another step needed? at the BackColor Property a little symbol shows that it is binded to MyColor in my forms binding source but the properties wont sync.

Comment: Are you also refreshing the form or panel or whatever object is displaying the color?

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`Colors`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.colors(v=vs.110).aspx) class.

```
public static Color redColor = Colors.Red;
public static Color greenColor = Colors.Green;
public static Color blueColor = Colors.Blue;
public static Color whiteColor = Colors.White;
```

Here is a pallete of the available colors:

[image]

If you want to create a new color, use [`Color.FromArgb();`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.drawing.color.fromargb(v=vs.110).aspx)

Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13670291/4802649) for more information on new colors.

Comment: My problem is not how to assign value to the variables but how to set the propety value thruogh the code and that the changes will show up in the designer, or some other way of setting variable color to controls. basicly I want the possibility of changing the colors in my app without having to change each control separately

Comment: Oh, sorry my bad. You can't view the changes in the designer because this code will be executed only at runtime. SO you should define the main color from the designer itself. Click a control and then click on properties.

Comment: But throgh the properties I cant only set constant color is there a way of setting it a varible color?